# I can not install ubuntu with windows 10 - Not enough space

Tags: 18.04, windows-10

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 2-in-1 with windows 10 installed, I want to install Ubuntu 18 either with windows or by erasing windows and formatting the PC. I created a bootable flash disk with ubuntu 18, and in the installation wizard, it tells me that I do not have enough space: you have only 3.9 GB while I have a free unallocated partition of more than 100 GB 
[Partiotions description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KBZn.png)

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you selecting the correct partition while installing ubuntu? it seems you are selecting the D drive. Can you attach a screen shot of the partition table when you are installing ubuntu?

Comment: 1) keep Windows installed in a dual-boot config just in case you need to do things like BIOS updates, or run apps that have no equivalent in Ubuntu, 2) when you made the unallocated space (from Windows, I presume) did you reboot Windows successfully?, 3) When you boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, and start `gparted`, how does it show the desired unallocated space... show me a screenshot please.